# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::create does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Can anyone know why this error exist => Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::create does not exist

Coding in controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'appointment_date' => 'required',
            'appointment' => 'required',
        ]);


        $appointment = auth()->user()->appointments->create($data);


        return redirect('/appointments/'.$appointment->id);
    }
```

Comment: It says it right there in the message: a Laravel collection doesn't have a `create()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods `auth()->user()->appointments` is a collection

Comment: you most likely meant to call `...->appointments()->create($data)` the actual relationship method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you forget use () for ->appointments(),
so try this

```
auth()->user()->appointments()->create($data);
```